# What does M Hayate mean?

Tags: street-fighter-iv

I've been trying to finish Makoto's challenge/training stages and it asks me to:

---

*Jump H Kick*

*Stand M Kick*

*M Hayate*

---

I can do all the others but I don't know what M Hayate Means, and I also have trouble linking them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Medium. It means use the medium version of the special move.

It should look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzC1xTv-eDs&feature=player_detailpage#t=58).